# Gstreamer on OSX

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, gstreamer, facetime, gst-launch

I'm trying to create a very simply Gstreamer pipeline where I have a source element that is my FaceTime camera and a sink element that is a udp sink.

I first install Gstreamer using the instructions [here](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Mac+OS+X). I ran some of the basic pipelines no problem; however, when I tried to use the following command

```
./gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src ! xviimagesink
```

I got the following error:

```
ERROR: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "v4l2src".
```

So I did some digging and turns out that the v4l2src plugin is in a gst-plugins-good. I installed these good plugins using macports using the following command:

```
port install gst-plugins-good
```

After a very long time everything installed without error. Now gst-launch appears in three places.

```
/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/0.10/bin/gst-launch-0.10
/opt/local/bin/gst-launch
/opt/local/bin/gst-launch-0.10
```

If I try to run the above mentioned pipline from any of those directories I still get

```
ERROR: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "v4l2src".
```

If I type the following command from anywhere I get some more errors but seems like it still is not finding v4lsrc.

```
gst-launch v4l2src ! xviimagesink
```

Gives:

```
Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
GConf Error: Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Not enough memory)
ERROR: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "v4l2src".
```

So it seems like I have GStreamer mess and I still can't get my camera to work because GStreamer can't find v4l2src.

Some help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`v4l2src` means "video-for-linux (ver.2) source".
since you are not running "linux", it is not so surprising that you cannot use "v4l2".

you might try to use the `osxvideosrc` (afaik this is in gstreamer-plugins-bad).

generally i suggest to check which elements are installed on your machine when you are looking for a a specific functionality, e.g.:

```
$ gst-inspect | grep -i video |grep -i source
```

PS: and usually i find it a good idea to throw some colorspace-converter (like `ffmpegcolorspace`) between a video-source and and -sink.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. That explains things. I ran the gst-inspect command when I was trying to figure this out and for obvious reasons never got the v4lsrc in the list. I will take a look at osxvideosrc.

Comment: Thanks umlaute for this answer! the inspect command did the trick for me. on macbook pro high sierra I needed this command to stream from the webcam. `gst-launch-1.0 autovideosrc device="/dev/video0" ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! autovideosink`

Answer (score 3):

For me those two works from MacPorts (https://www.macports.org/):

GStreamer 1.0, **applemedia:  avfvideosrc: Video Source (AVFoundation)**, use `device-index` parameter to select a device (index will vary depending on the connection order).

```
bash-3.2# port install gstreamer1*

iCeDeROM:~ cederom$ gst-inspect-1.0 |grep video | grep src
inter:  intervideosrc: Internal video source
decklink:  decklinkvideosrc: Decklink Video Source
applemedia:  qtkitvideosrc: Video Source (QTKit)
applemedia:  avfvideosrc: Video Source (AVFoundation)
ximagesrc:  ximagesrc: Ximage video source
videotestsrc:  videotestsrc: Video test source
autodetect:  autovideosrc: Auto video source
```

GStreamer 0.10 (**autodetect:  autovideosrc: Auto video source**)

```
bash-3.2# port install gstreamer0*

iCeDeROM:~ cederom$ gst-inspect-0.10 |grep video | grep src
ximagesrc:  ximagesrc: Ximage video source
inter:  intervideosrc: FIXME Long name
gsettings:  gsettingsvideosrc: GSettings video src
gconfelements:  gconfvideosrc: GConf video source
autodetect:  autovideosrc: Auto video source
applemedia:  qtkitvideosrc: Video Source (QTKit)
applemedia:  miovideosrc: Video Source (MIO)
videotestsrc:  videotestsrc: Video test source
```

I use `autovideosink` or `osxvideosink` for testing (second works faster, first use Xorg). Use `gst-inspect <module>` for module information.